# Espressioni colloquiali per esprimere il fatto di non andare a lezione

Tags: regional, idioms, phrase-request, colloquial

Quali espressioni colloquiali si usano per esprimere il fatto di non andare a lezione? Io conosco soltanto ["marinare la scuola" o "marinare le lezioni"](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/marinare/), che non so fino a che punto siano ancora in uso, ma immagino che ne esistano altre.

Come accade per la [lingua castigliana](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17020/), potrebbe darsi che ci sia una grande varietà di espressioni, dipendenti dall'utilizzo delle diverse varietà regionali dell'italiano (in castigliano, io ho sempre detto "hacer campana", o "fer campana" in catalano e, fino a poco tempo fa, non sapevo che questa locuzione si usasse soltanto dalle mie parti) ma penso che sarebbe interessante conoscerle.

Comment: Come si dice “marinare la scuola” nelle varie regioni d’Italia. https://blogdisilviaspatafora.wordpress.com/2015/05/12/espressioni-curiose-come-si-dice-marinare-la-scuola-nelle-varie-parti-ditalia/

Comment: ...che cita come fonte it.wiktionary.org...

Comment: Dalle mie parti si diceva bigiare

Comment: Dalle mie si diceva *bruciare*.

Comment: Dalle mie parti si utilizza "TAGLIARE LA SCUOLA" per indicare che al posto di andare a scuola si è fatto altro. Diciamo che il termine *marinare la scuola* non è più di utilizzo comune

Comment: Mi ricordo che quando ancora andavo a scuola avevamo cercato di fare un catalogo comprensivo intervistando ragazzi da varie regioni d'Italia. Il numero di varianti aveva superato facilmente le 100... (dalle mie parti si diceva *bruciare/bruxar* verso Treviso e *far manca* più verso Padova e Mestre, ma le variazioni locali sono immense..)

Comment: A Roma per me è familiare “fare sega”, ma interrogherò qualcuno più giovane per vedere se oggi si usano altre espressioni.

Comment: Si dovrebbe dare una risposta "community wiki" come quella di Spanish.SE?

Comment: @DaG _fare sega_ è attuale come sempre!

Answer (score 5):

In [questo articolo nel blog dell'Istituto Europeo Firenze](https://istitutoeuropeo.blogspot.com/2014/01/etimologie-e-modi-di-dire-italiani.html#:%7E:text=In%20Liguria%20si%20dice%20saltare,e%20fare%20puffi%20a%20Rimini.) si può leggere:

> Partiamo dal nord: in **Valle d’Aosta**, sentirete dire che quel ragazzo
> ha *schissato* la scuola, ma nel vicino **Piemonte** esistono già diverse
> varianti a seconda della provincia, anche se la più diffusa è
> *tagliare*. In **Lombardia** sentirete dire *scavallare* se vi trovate in
> Brianza, altrimenti *impiccare* in provincia di Bergamo, *bigiare* a
> Milano, mentre a Sondrio *salano* la scuola. In **Veneto** si dice *far
> manca*, ma anche *brusare* (bruciare) e *far berna*. Nelle Dolomiti
> bellunesi, esiste la variante *fare plao*. In **Trentino** troviamo i
> vocaboli delle regioni vicine, con qualche variante: *fare blao*, ma
> anche *bruciare* a Bolzano, *bigiare* a Trento. In **Friuli** la versione
> udinese è molto vicina all’italiano standard: *andare in marina*. Gli
> studenti di Trieste e Gorizia invece dicono *fare lipe* o *lippa*. In
> **Liguria** si dice *saltare, conigliare*, o *forcare* (come nella vicina
> Toscana). Se andate in **Emilia Romagna**, sentirete così tante varianti
> che vi si confonderanno le idee: per citarne qualcuna, *salare* a
> Piacenza, *fare buco* o *fare fuoco* a Bologna, *fare fuga* a Reggio Emilia
> e *fare puffi* a Rimini. Anche la **Toscana** non è da meno: a Firenze si
> usa dire *fare forca*, ma ad Arezzo *fare chiodo*, mentre a Livorno si *fa
> brucia* e a Pisa si *fa bu’a*, solo per dire alcune. In **Umbria** non c’è
> modo di sbagliarsi: si *fa salina*, mentre nelle **Marche** si *fa sega*, come
> nel **Lazio**. In **Abruzzo** sentirete un simpatico *fare cuppo* o *cuppare*,
> mentre nel vicino **Molise** si dice o *fare spago* o *fare filone*, come in
> **Campania**. In **Puglia** esistono molte varianti a seconda della provincia
> in cui ci si trova: nel Salento si usa *nargiare*, mentre nelle province
> settentrionali ritroviamo *fare filone* e *fare fruscio*. Anche in
> **Calabria** abbiamo l’imbarazzo della scelta: *fare sciampalè, addrazzare,
> zumpare* sono solo alcune delle varianti. In **Basilicata** si usano
> varianti delle regioni vicine, come *fare filone* e *azzuppà*; in **Sicilia**
> si dice *buttarsela* e in **Sardegna** *fare vela*.

Comment: Che cos'è l'“Istituto Europeo Firenze”? Una scuola di lingue?

Comment: Dal loro [sito ufficiale](https://www.istitutoeuropeo.org/) : "L’ISTITUTO EUROPEO è situato nel cuore di Firenze, nella strada più bella e famosa della città, via Tornabuoni, dove si trovano boutique e caffè delle firme più prestigiose del mondo. L’Istituto è da molti anni specializzato nell’insegnamento della lingua, arte, musica e cultura italiana a studenti stranieri."

Comment: Grazie, @abarisone!

Comment: Aggiungerei giusto un "balzare" che ho sentito da un amico di Biella (Piemonte)

Answer (score 2):

In Sardegna (a Sassari e nel nord Sardegna in genere) si dice *farsi ferie* con il riflessivo. *Fare vela*, citato nell'articolo si usa a Cagliari e nel sud Sardegna.